Screen lock keeps occuring on 24.04 even though I believe I've disabled it
I've recently did a fresh install of 24.04.
I'm having an issue where I believe I have disabled screen lock, but if I leave my computer for some time, it is locked when I come back to it. I only want screen lock to happen if I press "super+L".
Here is what my settings look like via the GUI. "Automatic Screen Lock" seems to be disabled.

Via the terminal I've also checked several settings:
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen

Which shows
false
true

Is there something I'm missing, could this be a bug?

I submitted a bug report about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/2064037
I was able to mostly resolve it by upgrading to Wayland and 550 nvidia drivers.

I think this feature is created to save more energy; Like Windows 11. It has an option that turns off screen and locks the computer after 3 minutes; To use less energy than normal when you don't use the computer for a short time.
